# require_once(): Failed opening required '../include/database.php'

Tags: php

есть файл localhost/tyanpost/account/obrlogin.php
в нём мне нужно подключить файл localhost/tyanpost/include/database.php
пишу так:

```
require_once '../include/database.php';
```

Выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Сообщайте абсолютный путь, а не относительный.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.dirname.php

Comment: @entithat, А как же `__DIR__`? :)

Comment: @Other, ну да, там в комментариях разные примеры есть:)

Comment: @Other, а как сообщить абсолютный путь?

Comment: @РоманПаничев, константой `__DIR__`, либо аналогично этому `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @entithat, что делает константа __DIR__ я понял, но не понял как с её помощью подключить нужный файл

Comment: @entithat, как мне подняться на 1 уровень выше?

Comment: Тогда начните изучать PHP с основ, там и поймёте как и что.

Comment: @РоманПаничев, dirname

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../include/database.php';
```